# Template Class return tuple or value, depend on parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I want to write a class which has a parameter pack and a function. This function should return the value itself, if there is only one type in the pack and otherwise it should return a tuple.
If there pack is empty it can return an empty tuple or void, I don't mind.

Something like this(pseudocode):

```
template<typename ...Args>
class A{
std::tuple<Args...> data;

#if sizeof...(Args)
std::tuple<Args...> get();
#else
Args[0] get();
#endif

};
```

I think my current solution is very complicated and it doesn't work if Args is empty.

Current solution:

```
template<bool EnableBool = true>
    typename std::enable_if<
            EnableBool && std::tuple_size_v<decltype(data)> == 1, typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(data)>::type>::type
get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++17 you can use `if constexpr` and return type will be deduced by compiler:

```
template<typename ...Args>
class A{
    std::tuple<Args...> data;
public:
    auto get()
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) > 1)
            return data;
        else if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 1)
            return std::get<0>(data);
        else 
            return;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A<int,double> a;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a.get()),std::tuple<int,double>>);
    A<> b;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b.get()),void>);
    A<int> c;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(c.get()),int>);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/axf91W)

Comment: Thanks, that was the thing I was searching for. Very nice combination of  if conexpr and auto type deduction.

Comment: +1 for the clean solution, but it should be noted that we can get the same result in c++11 (coders new to templates might mistakenly get the impression a solution to this requires c++17).

Comment: @Elliott, you are right, there are many ways to achive the same goal in C++. This is just one of them.